# Positive measure and $L^2$ space

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about measure theory.

Let $(E,\mathcal{B})$  be an arbitary measurable spase and let $m$ be a positive measure on $(E,\mathcal{B})$.

Let $f \in L^{2}(E;m)$ (fix).

$0 \leq\int fg\,dm\quad(\forall g \in L^{2}(E,m),\,g\geq0 \,m-a.e. ) $ implies that $f \geq0\,m-a.e.$?

We suppose $m$ is finite then for all $ \alpha < 0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 &\leq& (-\alpha) m( \{f \leq \alpha \} )\\
&=&(-\alpha)\int_{ \{f \leq \alpha \}} dm \\
&\leq&\int(-f) \chi_{ \{f \leq \alpha\}} dm\\
&=&-\int f \chi_{ \{f \leq \alpha\}} dm \leq 0 \,({\rm by\,assumption})
\end{eqnarray*}

Hense $m(\{ f \leq \alpha \})=0$. We get

\begin{eqnarray*}
m(\{f <0 \})=m(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{f \leq -\frac{1}{n}\})=\lim_{n \to \infty} m(\{f \leq -\frac{1}{n}\})=0
\end{eqnarray*}

If $m$ is $\sigma$-finite , assetion holds.

If $m$ is not necessarily $\sigma$-finite, assertion holds? thanks.

Comment: Note that $\{x \mid |f(x)| \geq 1/n\}$ is of finite measure for each $n$ (because of $f \in L^2$). Hence, $f$ vanishes outside a $\sigma$-finite set. I will let you take it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can reduce to the case where $m$ is $\sigma$-finite using the fact that the support of any integrable function must be $\sigma$-finite. After all, if we consider the sets

$$E_n = \left\{f^2 \ge \frac 1 n\right\}$$

then each $E_n$ must clearly have finite measure. Hence,

$$\{f > 0\} = \bigcup_n E_n$$

is $\sigma$-finite. Thus, replace your measure as needed and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it!

Answer (score 0):

For $f \in L^2(E,m)$ denote by $$f^+(x) := \max\{0,f(x)\} \qquad \quad f^-(x) := - \min\{0,f(x)\}$$ the positive and negative part of $f$, respectively. As $f \in L^2$, we have $f^- \in L^2$. Hence, by assumption,

$$0 \leq \int f(x) f^-(x) \, dm(x) = \int (f^+(x)-f^-(x)) \cdot f^-(x) \, dm(x) = - \int f^-(x)^2 \, dm(x).$$

using that $f^+(x) \cdot f^-(x) = 0$. As $f^-(x)^2 \geq 0$, this shows

$$0 = \int f^-(x)^2 \, dm(x).$$

Consequently, $f^-=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! your solution is easy to understand.